# xetex segoe cedil problem

Tags: fonts, xetex

I have a problem with xetex and unicode support. I have loaded Segoe Script as the font to use at some portions of my script. However, when it comes to some characters, they are *sometimes* displayed wrong.

I have generated a minimal example. When I compile that example, the cedillas of some c's appear weirdly at top, instead of bottom.

I have the same result when I use `\c{c}` and `\i` escapes of the characters.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[turkish,shorthands=off]{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\Segoe}{Segoe Script}

\begin{document} 
\Segoe

Çift çakmak çıkmaz sonuç. 

\c{C}ift \c{c}akmak \c{c}{\i}kmaz sonu\c{c}. 

\end{document}
```

The result is given below:

[image: mwe]

Note that in the third and fourth words, the cedillas appear at the top of the letters.

Why I am having this weird result, and how I can resolve the problem?

Comment: This is not from XeTeX I think: if I render that text (_Çift çakmak çıkmaz sonuç_) in that font (Segoe Script) in a different application, I get the same rendering as in your screenshot. It seems to be part of the font definition that at the end of a word, or when followed by dotless i, a caron must be used instead of cedilla (even though the  Unicode character is named 00E7  LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA).

Comment: (You can dump the `ttf` file of the Segoe Script font using `ttx`, and look at its tables: it has stuff like a glyph named `ccedilla.fin`.)

Comment: The solution here in XeTeX may be to not use the glyphs from the font, but instead position the accent manually. Or maybe force the regular c-cedilla glyph. Someone will know how to do that :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With firefox I get

[image]

from

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <style>
      p.zz {font-family: Segoe Script}
      </style>
  <body>
  <p>Çift çakmak çıkmaz sonuç.</p>
  <p class="zz">Çift çakmak çıkmaz sonuç.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

so it seems to be an error in the font.

it seems tricky to get the cedilla as an isolated ç already shows the v form, however you can force it using `\XeTeXglyph\XeTeXglyphindex"ccedilla"`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[turkish,shorthands=off]{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\Segoe}{Segoe Script}


\begin{document} 
\Segoe

Çift çakmak çıkmaz sonuç. 

\c{C}ift \c{c}akmak \c{c}{\i}kmaz sonu\c{c}. 

Çift çakmak çıkmaz sonuç. 

Çift çakmak \XeTeXglyph\XeTeXglyphindex"ccedilla" ıkmaz sonu\XeTeXglyph\XeTeXglyphindex"ccedilla" . 




\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried with Microsoft Word, where the cedillas appear at the correct location. After your post, I also tried on Notepad, which I repeat the problem. So, I think the problem is with the font itself. I will find another font. Thank you.

Comment: @Eagle got something working, see updated answer.

Comment: `\XeTeXglyph\XeTeXglyphindex"ccedilla"` doesn't work for me. I can output the glyph with a direct slot number `\XeTeXglyph722` (722 found by looking at the lua-file) but `\XeTeXglyphname\font722` outputs nothing and segoesc.lua shows no names for the glyphs. I get the wanted glyph when I surround e.g. with a: `aça`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer odd. I get the output shown with tl2017 pretest

Comment: What do you get in segoesc.lua after a compilation with lualatex? Is there a name at the `[231]` entry?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer different version of the font perhaps? I get   [231]={
   ["boundingbox"]={ 96, -555, 1417, 1042 },
   ["index"]=722,
   ["name"]="ccedilla",
   ["unicode"]=231,
   ["width"]=1075,
  },

Comment: @UlrikeFischer my version is ttf  and properties says `22 ‎August ‎2013, ‏‎16:36:36`

Comment: My version is a ttf too. otfinfo -v and luaotfload-names.lua report "version 5.01".

Comment: @UlrikeFischer 5.00 for me:-)